# Изменение настроек chromium из расширения

Tags: расширения, chromium

Нужна помощь по созданию расширений для Chromium-браузеров... В частности интересует вопрос, - **может ли расширение менять настройки браузера, и если да, то какие может, а какие нет?**

Под настройками браузера подразумеваются: домашняя страница, обработчики протоколов (tel, callto, mailto...), разрешения на использование флеша, защита от "опасных" сайтов, отправка в гугл статистики... в общем всё, что находится в `chrome://settings/`

То есть запуская браузер с параметром `--load-extension="<path>"`, расширение должно внести нужные настройки без вмешательства пользователя.

**Как меняются настройки из расширения?**